# Hosting .Net applications in the WSO2 ESB

Tags: .net, xml, soap, esb, wso2-esb

How do I host .Net applications into the WSO2 ESB?
I added the "wso2 hosting feature" to the ESB but seems not to be enough...

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Comment: @nuvio - what are you *actually* trying to achieve?  For example, do you have a .NET application that you want to connect to from the ESB?

Comment: @nuvio: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cann't host .net Application Into WSO2 ESB.

but you can use Wso2 ESB to communicate 2 Service that implemented using .NET Services.

this[1], link might be helpful to you.

[1]http://wso2.org/forum/thread/3885

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 ESB is a Java based product, so I wouldn't expect you to be able to host .NET applications.  You may have more success with a .NET based ESB such as [nservicebus](http://nservicebus.com).